# Ansible replace/delete specific entrys

Tags: regex, linux, ansible, yaml

I'm new to Ansible and I need to work with some yaml files.
For example.
the yaml file I need to edit has the following structure:

```
 Test-ABC:
    artifact: Test-ABC
    repository:
      Test-1:
        name: Test123
        release: 2024
        version: 1.1.0
        type: a
      Test-2:
        name: Test456
        release: 2023
        version: 2.0.1
        type: bs
```

So what I want to do is first remove all the entries under "repository:". So like this:

```
 Test-ABC:
    artifact: Test-ABC
    repository:
```

And then add some new values with input parameters that I defined earlier, e.g.

```
 Test-ABC:
    artifact: Test-ABC
    repository:
      New-Test:
        name: newTest123
        release: new2024
        version: new1.1.0
        type: new a
```

I should also mention that the yaml file has more entries than I've shown you, and they should not be affected by the changes.

I tried regexp and replace, but that just removed the Test-ABC line and so on.

```
 - name: "remove entries"
   replace:
     path: "file.yaml"
     regexp: "^\\s*{{ item.key }}:.*$"  
     replace: ""  
   loop: "{{ file['repository'] | dict2items }}"
```

Comment: What I have understand from your current description is that you are generating a new data structure / YAML file. So no need to edit remove replace delete, etc. Just write out the data structure / export into a YAML file.

Comment: Keep also in mind that [Not all strings are valid Ansible variable names.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names). See in example `ERROR! Invalid variable name in vars specified for Play: 'Test-ABC' is not a valid variable name`, since it contains a `-`.

Comment: So the data structure already exist. I need to replace the entries. Sry for the bad description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - include_vars:
      file: some.yml
      name: imported

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ imported['Test-ABC'] }}"

  - name: Update the fact
    ansible.utils.update_fact:
      updates:
        - path: "imported['Test-ABC'].repository"
          value:
            New-Test:
              name: newTest123
              release: new2024
              version: new1.1.0
              type: new a
    register: updated

  - copy:
      content: "{{ updated.imported | to_nice_yaml('indent=2') }}"
      dest: other.yml
```

will result into an file content of

```yaml
Test-ABC:
  artifact: Test-ABC
  more: entry
  not_shown: here
  repository:
    New-Test:
      name: newTest123
      release: new2024
      type: new a
      version: new1.1.0
  should: not be affected
```

**Documentation**

- [`include_vars` module – Load variables from files, dynamically within a task](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_vars_module.html)
- [Ansible: Variables, bracket notation or dot notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73544410/6771046)
- [`update_fact` module – Update currently set facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/update_fact_module.html)
- [Ansible: Add dictionary `item` into a YAML file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74089519/6771046)

Comment: ansible.utils.update_fact:

this solved my problem. Thank you for your detailed explanation